# Cómo sumar columnas que empiezan igual

Tags: python, pandas

Quería saber como puedo sumar columnas que empiezan igual. Lo he hecho de una manera, pero es muy largo, hay alguna manera mas fácil?

```
col_sellthrough= ['Absatz','Absatz.1','Absatz.2','Absatz.3','Absatz.4','Absatz.5','Absatz.6','Absatz.7','Absatz.8']

df['SELL THROUGH']= df[col_sellthrough].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: `col_sellthroug = ['Absatz', *(f'Absatz.{i}' for i in range(1, 10))]`

Answer (score 0):

Si con "largo" te refieres a no tener que aclarar cada columna a mano, esta respuesta puede servirte.

Con este código puedes obtener todas las columnas del DataFrame que empiezan por "Absatz":

```
col_sellthrough= [column for column in df.columns if(column.startswith("Absatz"))]
```

Esta sintaxis extraña y util se llama [comprensión de lista](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/). Es equivalente a:

```
col_sellthrough = []

for column in df.columns:
    if(column.startswith("Absatz")):
        col_sellthrough.append(column)
```

El atributo `columns` del DataFrame nos permite obtener todas las columnas que se encuentran en dicho.

Las cadenas tienen un método llamado [startswith](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), que como dice su nombre, nos permite saber con que subcadena empieza una cadena.